# Org mode evaluating propertized string removes properties

Tags: org-babel

See the following code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp 
(setq s #("abc" 0 3 (face (:foreground "red"))))
(pp s)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: #("abc" 0 3
:   (face
:    (:foreground "red")))
```

which is as expected, but literally just by evaluating,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
s
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: abc

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(pp s) ;; how did s change?
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: "abc"
```

I noticed this when calling <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
org-mode-line-string
#+END_SRC
```

actually removes fontification on the mode line of the current clocking task.

This does not happen for <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>(`eval-last-sexp`).

I'm using Org 9.1.9 on Emacs 26.3.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Let us have a look at [`org-no-properties`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/4b26289f00d2f67dc5652e5ab50c5bc74f2da105/lisp/org-macs.el#L1031) which is used for removing the properties from the result string:

```el
(defsubst org-no-properties (s &optional restricted)
  "Remove all text properties from string S.
When RESTRICTED is non-nil, only remove the properties listed
in `org-rm-props'."
  (if restricted (remove-text-properties 0 (length s) org-rm-props s)
    (set-text-properties 0 (length s) nil s))
  s)
```

For removing the text properties they use the destructive in-place functions `remove-text-properties` and `set-text-properties`.

That is the cause for the removal of the text properties from the original string.

They should copy the string with `seq-copy` before removing the properties.

The current behavior is unpleasant handling that could almost be regarded as a bug.
Maybe, you should write an enhancement request with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Currently you are responsible for copying. Change your source block to:

```el
(seq-copy org-mode-line-string)
```

Or use the advice I proposed in the answer to your [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/57432/2370).