# Why does org mode elisp evaluation not print text properties?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

With no special header argument values, I have

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(propertize "abc" 'face 'italic)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: abc
```

whereas <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> on the form gives me

```
#("abc" 0 3 (face italic))
```

why is there this discrepancy? Is there a difference between org mode source <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> and <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> has the key-binding `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` which runs `org-babel-exec-src-block` if `point` is inside a source block.
<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> runs `eval-last-sexp` which has nothing to do with Orgmode.

[`org-babel-execute-src-block`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/4b26289f00d2f67dc5652e5ab50c5bc74f2da105/lisp/ob-core.el#L740) uses `org-babel-insert-result` for inserting the result into the Org buffer. There, [`org-no-properties`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/4b26289f00d2f67dc5652e5ab50c5bc74f2da105/lisp/ob-core.el#L2238) removes the text properties from the result string.

I assume that they remove text properties because many of the properties would immediately be overwritten by `font-lock` fontification anyway.

The following advice of `org-babel-insert-result` defines a new `:result` flag `props` (or `properties`).
Source blocks where the `:results` header argument contains that flag keep the text properties on the result string.

```el
(require 'find-func)
(with-current-buffer
    (find-file-noselect (find-library-name "ob-core.el"))
  ;; This is a hack.
  ;; `org-no-properties' is defined by `defsubst' and the byte-compiler replaces the symbol with the lambda.
  ;; We need the definition of `org-babel-insert-result' containing the symbol `org-no-properties'.
  ;; Therefore, we eval the defun for `org-babel-insert-result' in the source file.
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward "(defun org-babel-insert-result")
  (eval-defun nil))

(defun org+-babel-insert-result-with-props (fun result result-params &rest args)
  "Avoid removing text properties in `org-babel-insert-result'.

Add the new result type \"raw-props\" to Org source blocks.
With this result type text properties are not removed from the result.

This is an :around advice for `org-babel-insert-result' as FUN.
RESULT, RESULT-PARAMS, and ARGS are passed to FUN."
  (if (or (member "props" result-params)
      (member "properties" result-params))
      (cl-letf* (((symbol-function 'org-no-properties)
          (lambda (str &rest _args) str)))
    (apply fun result
           (delete "properties" (remove "props" result-params))
           args))
    (apply fun result result-params args)))

(advice-add 'org-babel-insert-result :around #'org+-babel-insert-result-with-props)
```

But that only works reliably with `:result` type `raw`.
For an example the result string of the following source block is colored red:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results raw drawer props
(propertize "string" 'font-lock-face 'hi-red-b)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Another idea is use `prin1-to-string` to escape the value as string.

Comment: @xuchunyang Sorry, `prin1-to-string` does not work: If you wrap the propertized string in `prin1-to-string` the read-representation of the string is inserted as result and not the propertized string.

Comment: It seems that's OP wanted as `C-x C-e`.

Comment: @xuchunyang Please, post an alternative answer if you assume that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Sorry for the bother. I posted my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> why is there this discrepancy? Is there a difference between org mode source C-c C-c and C-x C-e?

As Tobias's answer mentioned, `C-x C-e` and Org Mode's `C-c C-c` are two different commands, so it's not a surprise if their results are different. For example, `C-x C-e` after `42` prints `42 (#o52, #x2a, ?*)`, as you can see, `C-x C-e` decides to print `42` not only in decimal form but also octal, hex and character form, however, no one asks Org Mode's `C-c C-c` to do the same.

---

As for your particular example, you can escape the string value once more to prevent Org from removing the text properties with `prin1-to-string` or `format`:

```
#+begin_src elisp
(prin1-to-string (propertize "abc" 'face 'italic))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: #("abc" 0 3 (face italic))

#+begin_src elisp
(format "%S" (propertize "abc" 'face 'italic))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: #("abc" 0 3 (face italic))
```

Comment: You could mention your `prin1-to-string` version of the source block. Maybe, the OP really wants to have that instead of the propertized string.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the reminder. I've done that.